# How to integrate activities between developer and tester in scrum sprint

Tags: agile-processes

Good day 
Any suggesion or opinoin about activities between tester and developer in scrum sprint 
Does the tester feed his acceptance test (ATDD from acceptance criteria) to developer to start coding the user story and if the developer finish coding does the tester take the implemented story and start his (ATDD) execution.
Plus , what is the main role for the system analysis team(where it was generating srs from brs in waterfall model)
In our company we try to use Agile instead of waterfall, so I highly appreciate your help

Comment: What do you mean by "srs" and "brs"? Also, what do you mean by an "analysis team"? Is this team separate from your Scrum team?

Comment: Sorry, My company use a waterfall model, the system analyst team resopinsble for converting the (Business Requirments Specification) which written by business analyst team to (Sofrware Requirment Specification) which represent the input for software developer...we try to move to scrum and we have changing role problem

Comment: Thsi question fits better @ https://pm.stackexchange.com/. As the tag description says, these questions are considered offtopic here at SO.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a huge range of approaches to how development and testing are combined in a sprint.

One approach I think works well is to have acceptance tests written in advance of the development.

The steps would be as follows:

- Work items are allocated to the next sprint
- Analysts, testers and developers work together to identify the acceptance tests for the selected work items
- The tests are built and then run, ideally in continuous integration
- All the tests fail as no code has yet been written
- Development starts on the work items
- Development work proceeds until all the tests pass

Ideally all of this is done within the sprint or in the days just proceeding the start of the sprint. Some teams find they need a bit more time to do the analysis and preparation of acceptance tests, so they may choose to do this one or two weeks in advance of the sprint start.

You have to be careful not to do preparation too far in advance though, as to follow an agile approach we want to be able to respond to changes in requirements/priorities.

Comment: do you mean that the acceptance test would be the input to developers, I think that the team(developer, tester...) will define acceptance criteria for each user story in story workshop isn't true? Also I think that in each sprint the tester will prepare the acceptance criteria as acceptance test and this acceptance test will be the developer input to start coding ??? Do you agree with me

Comment: Yes, exactly. The only thing I would add is that in some teams the roles are not quite so clearly defined. For example, I have worked with developers that get involved with writing acceptance tests.

Comment: Good, but what you said reduce the testing team responsiblity, what about old project manager role, can he be scrum master, we have alarge team(mobile and web developer, testing team, analyst team) how can you advice me to do success agile transition you can guid me with headlines.

Comment: If we are more than scrum team, how we can divide the backlog user story between us do you prefer alone scrum team for each project, you can imagine our current situation with 50 developer 40 tester and 25 business and system analyst with waterfall,

Comment: Sounds like you have lots more questions to post on stack overflow!

Comment: What the problem if I have?

Comment: The StackExchange format suggests specific questions with specific answers. It's not a problem to raise separated questions, it's not that good to pile up questions on top of the same question.